# Data Table y angular 4

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Mi problema es que no cargan los datos traídos de mi API en Laravel dentro del datatable en Angular.

#### view-component.ts

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string;
  rol: Roles;

  constructor(
     private _router: Router,
     private _route : ActivatedRoute,
     private _service: StrService
    ) {
     this.title = 'List Roles';
     this.rol = new Roles('');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('View Roles initialized');
    this.Roles();
  }

  Roles() {
    this._service.getRoles().subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.code === 200) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.rol= response.datos;
          }, 2000);
                console.log(this.rol);
          }
        },
      error => console.log(<any>error)
    );
}
```

#### view-component.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <table id="entry-grid" datatable="ng" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 1%" class="text-center">No.</th>
        <th>Name rol</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr align="left" *ngFor="let producto of rol">
        <td>{{producto.id}}</td>
        <td>{{producto.denominacion}}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="botones" *ngIf="confirmado != producto.id">
            <a (click)="borrarConfirm(producto.id);" class="btn btn-md btn-danger">Borrar</a>
          </div>
          <div class="botones" *ngIf="confirmado== producto.id">
            <a (click)="onDeleteProducto(producto.id);" class="btn btn-md btn-danger">Quiero eliminarlo</a>
            <a (click)="cancelarConfirm();" class="btn btn-md btn-warning">Cancelar</a>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="botones">
            <a [routerLink]="['/dashboards/editrol', producto.id]" class="btn btn-md btn-warning">Editar</a>
          </div>                
        </td>
      </tr>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

> La tabla muestra los datos pero debajo muestra: ***Not data available in table***.

### ¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: Prueba con `this.rol = response.json().datos`

Answer (score 1):

Define bien la variable que quieras bindear a la vista HTML, sería:

```
rol: Roles[]; //de tipo array
```

ya que estas haciendo uso de una directiva *nfFor y necesitas recorrer un objeto de tipo array.

`*ngFor="let producto of rol"`

Tambien revisa que es lo que te devuelve tu api, a mi parecer te subscribes a un `Observable<Roles[]>`  y en caso de ser así no es mas que hacer lo siguiente:

```
Roles() {
    this._service.getRoles().subscribe(
      (response: Roles[]) => {
        //comprueba que te devuelva un array de Roles
        console.log(response)
        this.rol= response;
        },
    error => console.log(<any>error)
    );
}
```

Comment: Mi api trae puros json amigo , d igual manera revisare muchas gracias

Comment: puedes subir lo que retorna tu api?

Comment: {
"msg":"Token Encontrado",
"status":"Successfull",
"datos":[
{
"id":**,
"name":"*",
"email":"**********",
"password":"***************************************",
"remember_token":null,
"token_ref":"**************************",
"confirm_email":1,
"refence_token":"*******************************",
"created_at":"2017-08-26 02:05:15",
"updated_at":"2017-08-26 02:05:15",
"perfil":[]
}
],
"apisign":"********************************",
"code":200
}   esta es otra respuesta pero basicamente todas mis respuestas las retorno asi

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable sea que en el momento de obtener los datos en tu respuesta estos no tengan el formato adecuado que esperas, JSON.

> **this.role = response.json().datos** en vez de **this.rol = response.datos**

Si utilizas el cliente http de angular 4.3 por defecto tus peticiones ya estarán parseadas.